# Authenticate once to both ARM and ASM in Azure PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure

With Switch-AzureMode now deprecated, is it possible to authenticate *once* in a script instead of prompting separately with both Add-AzureRmAccount and Add-AzureAccount? This is for a script that uses Service Bus that is not yet available in ARM, so it needs Add-AzureAccount, but all other resources in the script are managed with AzureRm cmdlets.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware it is not possible to authenticate to both ASM and ARM you need to call both logins individually. However you can store the credentials so you are not asked to login. Once you have permissions properly set you can have the same set of credentials login to both. Meaning that you can have the same pscredential object that can be passed.

So you end up with something like

```
    Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $credential -TenantId $Tenant
    Add-AzureAccount -Credential $credential -TenantId $Tenant
```

Personally I have developed a small module that takes care of logging in to both ASM and ARM. With the script I have a `Select-Subscription` cmdlet that takes a subscription name and logs in.

At the backend the script downloads an encrypted credential file, decrypts it, and the individually logs into both. This way whenever there is a password change I create a new encrypted file and that is propagated to all active scripts.

It takes a little bit more management to start with, and a couple of prerequisites when you install a new script (a decryption cert, and the module) but once they're there It makes life a lot quicker.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a service principal with an x.509 certificate for ARM auth and configure the same certificate as a management cert fir ASM auth. This would allow you to silently sign in to both ASM and ARM.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal/

Comment: This still has the problem that you would need to individually call Add-AzureRmAccount and  Set-AzureSubscription in order to login, and Add-AzureRmAccount still needs to be called explicitly per session (I've not used management certs for a long time! so can't remember the mechanics there)

Comment: The operational word was "silently." Using certs you can avoid popups.